# What databases have optimization for functions, in order to use indices?

Tags: database, indexing, b-tree

Suppose, I have a float column and a a b-tree index and a million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
     val FLOAT,
     KEY (val)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (random(-1000, 1000)), (random(-1000, 1000)), ...
```

(1M rows)

Now, if I want to make a query like

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE abs(val) > param
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE int(val) % 2; /* odd integer numbers only */
```

What databases can optimize this to use the index on `val`, so that I don't have to use an index on the expression I check, or reverse expression myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any DBMS can use a "plain" index on `val` if you use that column in a function or expression.

The main reason is that the result of applying the function could make the index lookup very expensive at best (basically creating an index based on the expression "on the fly") or plain wrong in the worst case in case the index lookup for the "plain" value returns a completely different row than the index lookup on the result of the expression (which is very likely to happen).

Answer (score 0):

I know [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) can do it. See [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html), but you create an index on the *expression*.

Using your examples:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test( abs(val) ); -- function calls don't require surrounding brackets
CREATE INDEX ON test( (int(val) % 2) ); -- arbitrary expressions require surrounding brackets
```

Comment: I though the question was if any DBMS can use an index on `val` **without** defining a function based index.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can do it. It will just work because the optimizer will match the expression in your query to the index.

Comment: Will it run the expression/function on the index values?

Comment: Can you give a link to a documentation page on this?

Comment: The first of many Google results: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-indexed-computed-columns-to-improve-performance

Comment: Again, it's an additional column/index.

Comment: Oh I see. I misread your question. Of course SQL Server can do this, if you have an existing index on val. I just verified that.